# Pyunit: "Import Site"

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Using pyUnit to do what is currently a very small and simple unit test I am getting the message:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
...
____________________________________________
Ran 3 tests in 0.094S
```

When I rerun the unit test with the -v parameter, it returns verbose information about each of the 3 tests and has no error or failure messages.

What does this message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to know is that the message you're seeing is from the Python interpreter, and has nothing to do with pyUnit.  The -v in the message refers to "python -v".

As to why you can't import site, and why running pyUnit with -v makes the error go away, I don't know.  Do you have your own site.py?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why, but this message has vanished over the course of continuing to work on the project.  Thanks, its good to know its from the interpreter.